# MySQL regular expression

Tags: java, mysql, regex

please suggest for a change in regular expression `'^({0,1}{0,1}){0,1}[7-9][0-9]{0,1}{0,1}{0,1}[0-9]{1}[0-9]{7}$'` to use with a MySQL statement.
This expression worked perfect using Java but failed using MySQL. This pattern is to match a 10 digit number starting with [7-9].

I executed MySQL statement:

```
select '11' REGEXP '^({0,1}{0,1}){0,1}[7-9][0-9]{0,1}{0,1}{0,1}[0-9]{1}[0-9]{7}$'
```

But it returned following error:

> ERROR 1139 (42000): Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp

Answer (score 2):

**'[7-9]\d{9}'**, perhaps?

Edit: Wait, no, I guess \d isn't valid in MySQL regexes, so **'^[7-9][[:digit:]]{9}$'**

What exactly is the **({0,1}{0,1}){0,1}**  bit at the start meant to do?